# Use seekbar to transition between two drawables

Tags: android, seekbar, transition, nine-patch

I've setup a seekbar, which is intended to be used to adjust the transparency of an image.

I've also got two nine patch images (one is just a transparent version of the other).

What I'd like to do is have the seekbar progress set the amount of transition between one drawable and the other. Is this possible? How Would I go about it?

```
@Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {

//Set percentage of transition between image1 and image2 equal to progress here.

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
image1.setAlpha(progress);
Image2.setAlpha(100-progress);
```

As one gets more transparent, the other becomes more opaque.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm trying to avoid using setAlpha (it doesn't worj for some reason, on my 9 patch images used as a layout background). That's why I've used a transparent 9-patch, else I'd just use one image and set the alpha on that image.